# error compiling qt mysql driver

Tags: qt, qmake, qtsql, qsqlquery

I'm trying to build the qt mysql driver plugin. I already have mysql(xampp) installed. The .pro file is in `C:\myTools\Qt\QtSDK\QtSources\4.8.1\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql`.
This is a copy of my .pro file

```
TARGET = qsqlmysql
SOURCES = main.cpp
include(../../../sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.pri)
INCLUDEPATH += C:/myTools/xampp/mysql/include
LIBS+=C:/myTools/xampp/mysql/lib/libmysql.lib
include(../qsqldriverbase.pri)
```

However, I am still getting the error:

```
cannot find -llibmysql
error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I cross-checked my library and include path. They were intact.

Comment: try ``LIBS+=-LC:/myTools/xampp/mysql/lib/ -llibmysql``

Comment: You seem not to have selected an answer for your question. What is missing still? What more can we do for you? It is strange that you have not selected any replies for any of your questions!

Comment: I really do not understand why you do not select answers for your questions...

Answer (score 0):

`cannot find -llibmysql`

That should be -lmysql which you can achieve by passing `-lmysql` to `LIBS`. You will also need to pass the path to the location where the library itself resides.

So, you should be having something like this:

```
TARGET = qsqlmysql
SOURCES = main.cpp
include(../../../sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.pri)
INCLUDEPATH += C:/myTools/xampp/mysql/include
LIBS+=-LC:/myTools/xampp/mysql/lib -lmysql
include(../qsqldriverbase.pri)
```